# Problem with drawing borders around slides in latex beamer handouts with Adobe Reader

Tags: beamer, framed, presentations

I am using the LaTeX `beamer` package and `handoutWithNotes` package to create a presentation with notes and rectangle around each slide.

```
\documentclass[handout]{beamer} 

\usetheme{Madrid}
\usecolortheme{seagull}
\usepackage{handoutWithNotes}

\pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1 with notes landscape}[a4paper,border shrink=5mm]

\pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{1}{border code=\pgfusepath{stroke}}
\pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{2}{border code=\pgfusepath{stroke}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}\frametitle{numbered lists}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Introduction to  \LaTeX  
\item Course 2 
\item Termpapers and presentations with \LaTeX 
\item Beamer class
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}\frametitle{numbered lists with pause}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Introduction to  \LaTeX \pause 
\item Course 2 \pause 
\item Termpapers and presentations with \LaTeX \pause 
\item Beamer class
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

It works fine in other softwares (preview, PDFview, .. etc) NOT adobe reader.

[image]

The problem is that the rectangle seems to disappear when I open the pdf file with Adobe Reader.

[image]

Comment: This is just a visual artifact at the zoom level you're viewing at. A very common occurrence between different viewers. If this is a problem, you might consider adding `\setlength\arrayrulewidth{0.6pt}` (or some larger length) in your preamble. See [Adobe Reader and `xcolor` within a table breaks the line render](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/53253/5764).

Comment: Thanks @Werner, but it did not solve the problem. I have tried it with different lengths but still the border is no where to be seen :(

Comment: They are there when you zoom in. As such, they will also print out. I am able to see them when I view the output PDF @ 150%.