# \rowcolors causes missing vertical lines

Tags: tables, color

When using \rowcolors to alternate row coloring, some vertical lines are missing in the restulting table.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\rowcolors{2}{gray!25}{white}
\begin{tabular}{l|ccc|cc|ccc|}
           & A & B & C & D & E & F & G & H \\\hline   
Verfahren  & p & a & p & a & a & a & a & a \\
Verfahren  & p & a & p & a & a & a & a & a \\
Verfahren  & p & a & p & a & a & a & a & a \\
Verfahren  & p & a & p & a & a & a & a & a \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

If I manually insert  `\rowcolor{gray!25}` for every other row, the lines are correct for the "white" rows (since they are not explicitly set to to `white` as in the `\rowcolors` case)

Am I missing something?

Comment: They are probably there, try zooming in or out in your pdf viewer, or printing or trying a different viewer.

Comment: Yes, indeed, zooming shows it's there...Can't believe that the solution is so simple. I didn't expect different rendering behaviour for different lines. Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Adobe Reader and `xcolor` within a table breaks the line render](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/53253/5764)