# Tabular and lines displaying problem with Adobe

Tags: tables, windows, displaystyle, adobe

Considering the following code (**MWE**) :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|l|c|r|}
  \hline
  Some & \cellcolor{blue!25}coloured & contents \\
  \hline
  \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\cellcolor{blue!25} multicolumn coloured} & \cellcolor{blue!6} other color \\ \hline
  Some & \cellcolor{blue!15}coloured & contents \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

I am having issues with tabular lines displaying, as you can notice on the following pictures.

---

**With Evince (LINUX) :**

[image: Linux displays]

No problem so far.

---

**With Adobe (WINDOWS) :**

[image: windows display]

As you can see, lines are not displayed properly.

How can I fix this problem ? I wish my document would be displayable whatever the operating system.

---

**NOTES :**

- I tried to follow this post proposal [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53253/adobe-reader-and-xcolor-within-a-table-breaks-the-line-render), but unfortunately, it didn't fixed the problem.
- I compile on Linux with pdflatex, version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013/Debian)
- That's the same issue with no multicolumn as you can see on below : 
  [image: with no multicolumn, windows]

Comment: You use pdftex, tex or something else to make your document?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: I think the problem is coming from \multicolumn{}. What append if you have always 3 column each row?

Comment: It is only a viewer issue. Nothing wrong. Try to zoom and at some zoom level you will see lines properly.

Comment: @Harish Kumar : "It's only", well, maybe, however I wish it could be solved, because it doesn't really look professionnal.

Comment: @RomainPicot : same problem, as you can see on my edit.

Comment: A simpler solution than overlapping tables  uses the rules from `hhline` or `booktabs`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quite crude workaround is to set the table twice, the second time without background colors. Also the rule thickness can be increased by setting `\arrayrulewidth`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor
\begin{document}

\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1.5\arrayrulewidth}% 50% thicker
\def\tmp{%
  \begin{tabular}{|l|c|r|}
    \hline
    Some & \cellcolor{blue!25}coloured & contents \\
    \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\cellcolor{blue!25}multicolumn coloured} &
    \cellcolor{blue!6}other color \\ \hline
    Some & \cellcolor{blue!15}coloured & contents \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}%
}
\leavevmode
\rlap{\tmp}%
\begingroup
  \renewcommand*{\cellcolor}[1]{}%
  \tmp
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

**Remarks:**

- LaTeX removes spaces at the begin and end of a cell. But the space *after* `\cellcolor{...}` is inside the cell and is *not* automatically removed.

### Automation

The procedure can be automated to some degree. The following example at least supports column types `l`, `c`, `r`, `p`, `m`, `b`. Internals are redefined to catch the cell contents in boxes and to replace them with empty boxes of the same dimensions.

Unsupported are text inside `@{...}`, `longtable`, ...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor

\makeatletter
\let\org@insert@column\insert@column
\newcommand*{\dummy@insert@column@h}{%
  \begingroup
    \setbox0=\hbox\bgroup\begingroup
      \org@insert@column
    \endgroup\egroup
    \setbox2=\hbox{}%
    \wd2=\wd0 %
    \ht2=\ht0 %
    \dp2=\dp0 %
    \copy2 %
  \endgroup
}
\newcommand*{\dummy@endpbox}{%
  \@finalstrut\@arstrutbox
  \egroup
  \begingroup
    \setbox0=\lastbox
    \setbox2=\hbox{}%
    \wd2=\wd0 %
    \ht2=\ht0 %
    \dp2=\dp0 %
    \copy2 %
  \endgroup
  \hfil
}
\newcommand*{\dummy@classz}{%
  \@classx
  \@tempcnta \count@
  \prepnext@tok
  \@addtopreamble{%
    \ifcase \@chnum
      \hfil \d@llarbegin
      \dummy@insert@column@h
      \d@llarend \hfil
    \or
      \hskip1sp\d@llarbegin
      \dummy@insert@column@h
      \d@llarend \hfil
    \or
      \hfil\hskip1sp\d@llarbegin
      \dummy@insert@column@h
      \d@llarend
    \or
      $\vcenter
      \@startpbox{\@nextchar}\insert@column \dummy@endpbox
      $%
    \or
      \vtop
      \@startpbox{\@nextchar}\insert@column \dummy@endpbox
    \or
      \vbox
      \@startpbox{\@nextchar}\insert@column \dummy@endpbox
    \fi
  }%
  \prepnext@tok
}
\newcommand*{\tabulardummysetup}{%
  \renewcommand*{\cellcolor}[1]{\null}%
  \let\@classz\dummy@classz
}
\newcommand{\tabularfix}[1]{%
  \def\tabularfix@contents{\ignorespaces#1\ifhmode\unskip\fi}%
  \leavevmode
  \rlap{\tabularfix@contents}%
  \begingroup
    \tabulardummysetup
    \tabularfix@contents
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1.5\arrayrulewidth}

\begin{document}

\tabularfix{%
  \begin{tabular}[t]{|l|c|r|}
    \hline
    Some & \cellcolor{blue!25}coloured & contents \\
    \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\cellcolor{blue!25}multicolumn coloured} &
    \cellcolor{blue!6}other color \\ \hline
    Some & \cellcolor{blue!15}coloured & \multicolumn{1}{p{20mm}|}{contents} \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}%
}

\bigskip

\begingroup
  \tabulardummysetup
  \begin{tabular}{|l|c|r|}
    \hline
    Some & \cellcolor{blue!25}coloured & contents \\
    \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|@{\kern\tabcolsep}c|}{\cellcolor{blue!25}multicolumn coloured} &
    \cellcolor{blue!6}other color \\ \hline
    Some & \cellcolor{blue!15}coloured & \multicolumn{1}{p{20mm}|}{contents} \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}%
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Indeed, it seems to  fix the bad displays. Two questions now: 1) is it possible to only double all except the text in the tabular (now it seems weird on evince). 2) Is there a way to automate this process into my file (I actually have several tables in that way).

Answer (score 1):

The package `nicematrix` has tools designed to address that problem. With the environment `{NiceTabular}` of that package, the rules won't disappear because the colored panels are drawn before the rules (with informations written previously on the `aux` file: that's why you need several compilations).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{NiceTabular}{lcr}[colortbl-like,hvlines]
  Some & \cellcolor{blue!25}coloured & contents \\
  \Block[fill=blue!25]{1-2}{multicolumn} & & \cellcolor{blue!6}other color \\ 
  Some & \cellcolor{blue!15}coloured & contents \\
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]

If you prefer, it's also possible to specify the formatting instructions outside the main array (the output is the same).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{NiceTabular}{lcr}[hvlines]
\CodeBefore
\cellcolor{blue!25}{1-2,2-1,2-2,3-2}
\cellcolor{blue!6}{2-3}
\Body
  Some        & coloured & contents \\
  \Block{1-2}{multicolumn} & & other color \\ 
  Some        & coloured & contents \\
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{document}
```