# rowcolor removes the vertical lines of the table

Tags: tables, rowcolor, cellcolor

After compiling (using  `pdflatex`) the following

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,amsxtra,amsopn}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
\rowcolor{lime!20}Item 1 & Item 2 & Item 3 \\
\hline
text & text & text\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

some of the borders of the table is invisible. After zooming in, the borders are visible. I observe this type of strange behaviour when dealing with such tables using `\rowcolor` or `\cellcolor` command. How to fix the code so that the borders of the output table are visible without zooming.

Comment: For me, it doesn't remove anythging. Which pdfviewer do you use?

Comment: Related: [Tabular and lines displaying problem with Adobe](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/173391/134144). You could either increase the width of the lines or redraw your table using a `tikz` matrix or alternatively the `cals` package.

Comment: I see also the vertical lines. The technical problem is that some pdf viewer at some scales are not able to show well that lines. The true problem is that I can see that lines, and  also if that document is printed.  Believe me, a table is *always* better [only with horizontal lines](https://inf.ethz.ch/personal/markusp/teaching/guides/guide-tables.pdf).

Comment: @ Bernard: Adobe Reader DC

Comment: @ leandriis: How to modify with `cals` package?

Answer (score 5):

Another option would be the new `tabularray` package ([CTAN](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabularray)). It has the command `\SetRow` which you can use to modify all properties of the current row, including color. Using that, vertical lines appear correct with Adobe Acrobat Reader.

[image: correct vertical lines]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,amsxtra,amsopn}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
    rowcolor solution
    
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        \rowcolor{lime!20}Item 1 & Item 2 & Item 3 \\
        \hline
        text & text & text\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \vspace{1cm}
    
    tabularray solution
    
    \begin{tblr}{|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        \SetRow{lime!20} Item 1 & Item 2 & Item 3 \\
        \hline
        text & text & text\\
        \hline
    \end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

Note: The package has different (better) default spacing, which you can modify with the `rowsep` and `colsep` keys as you like.

Edit: I don't exactly know what causes it, but the vertical **and** horizontal lines are the not all the same width for the colored cells with the `colortbl` solution. It seems as if the `tabularray` "encoding" is superior, since it does not cause any artifacts no matter the zoom level.

As Zarko pointed out in his comment, the `tabularray` package also supports a very nice key-value interface for formatting.

```
\begin{tblr}{
        hlines, vlines, cells = {c}, 
        row{1} = {bg=lime!20},
    }
    Item 1 & Item 2 & Item 3 \\ 
    text   & text   & text   \\     
\end{tblr}
```

Comment: In my test table the widths of lines are equal in all rows. BTW, coorect code for `tabularray` is: `\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
                 cells = {c},
                 row{1} = {bg=lime!20}}
    Item 1 & Item 2 & Item 3 \\
    text   & text   & text   \\
    \end{tblr}
\end{document}`. Anyway, +1 ;-)

Comment: @Zarko I also prefer the key-value syntax :) However, I wanted to keep the answer as close to the original code to avoid additional confusion.

Comment: @Zarko I have added the key-value formatting option to the answer now.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`. Rules won't seem to disappear, whatever PDF viewer (and level of zoom) you use.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

With \verb|{tabular}| (and \verb|colortbl|).

\medskip
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
\rowcolor{lime!20}Item 1 & Item 2 & Item 3 \\
\hline
text & text & text\\
\hline
\end{tabular}


\vspace{1cm}

With \verb|{NiceTabular}| of \verb|nicematrix|.

\medskip
\begin{NiceTabular}{|c|c|c|}[colortbl-like]
\hline
\rowcolor{lime!20}Item 1 & Item 2 & Item 3 \\
\hline
text & text & text\\
\hline
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: (+1). At coloring of tables the package  `nicematrix` is superior to others.  BTW, instead of `\usepackage{xcolor}\usepackage{colortbl}` I would write `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}`

Comment: @Zarko: Good idea. I will modify.

Comment: @Zarko can you elaborate on this? Why is `nicematrix`  superior to other packages such as say `tabularray` ?

Comment: @marv, i mean regarding coloring cells and rows.  No one of others handle this so good. In general in my list the `tabularray` is the first :-)