# Position of text and arrows in TikZ matrix

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-matrix

I want to put a text inside a TikZ `matrix`, but it always begins from the bottom !. So, my qusetion is how I can force it to begin from the top?

My MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}

        \usetikzlibrary{
                arrows, chains, matrix, 
                positioning, 
                shadows,
                shapes, shapes.callouts,graphs, calc,
                shapes.geometric,
                shapes.misc,
                intersections,
               matrix, % to draw a table
              fit                  
                }

 %\newcommand{\vlab}[2]{%
        %           \tikz[baseline,inner sep=0] \node[anchor=base] (#1){#2};
            %       }

\begin{document}


 \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={anchor=base,text depth=.5ex},baseline]
  \matrix %[draw=red]
   {
     \node[text height=2ex,fill=Orange!30,text width=6cm] {Local case}; & \node[text height=2ex,fill=Green!30,text width=7cm]{Global case}; \\
     \node[text height=6cm,fill=Yellow!30,align=left,text width=6cm] (noda) {
        \begin{itemize}
           \item We have \[\left[\bar \theta\right]=\left[\bar\partial (h^{-1}\partial h)\right]=c_1(\mathcal L)\,
                  =\left[K\right]\]  \\
           \item Since  $h=\exp(\mathcal K)$ we have:
                \[
                    \theta = \exp(-\mathcal K)\partial (\exp(\mathcal K))= \tikz[baseline,inner sep=0] 
                    \node[anchor=base](Kpot){$\partial\mathcal K$};
                    \tikz[baseline,inner sep=0] \node[below= of Kpot](Kpot2){\scriptsize So a K\"ahler transf. corresponds to a gauge 
                          transformation };
                     \tikz[overlay]\draw[->,red] (Kpot) to (Kpot2);
                \]
        \end{itemize}        
          }; 
     & \node[fill=Cyan!30,text height=6cm,,text width=7cm] {
      \begin{itemize}
        \item $\mathcal L$ is a flat bundle i.e $h=cst$\\
        \item Since $\theta \sim \partial h$, we can choose a vanishing connection:
            \[
                \theta=\bar \theta=0
             \]
      \end{itemize}       
               };\\
        %\node[fill=Purple] {a}; & \node[fill=LightBlue] {X}; & \node[fill=Aquamarine] {g}; \\
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Concerning your example, there are some issues:

- A `\matrix` already creates nodes, so I don't think that nesting nodes is advisable.
- You need to enclose each `\item` inside curly braces when inside a `\matrix`, like: `\item{<content goes here>}`
- For coloring a cell, use `|[fill=<color>]|`

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\usetikzlibrary{
    arrows, chains, matrix, 
    positioning, 
    shadows,
    shapes, shapes.callouts,
    graphs, calc,
    shapes.geometric,
    shapes.misc,
    intersections,
    matrix,fit,           
}

\newcommand{\tikzmark}[2]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture, anchor=base west] \node[text depth=, text width=] (#1) {#2};}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix [
matrix of nodes,
nodes in empty cells,
every node/.style={align=left},
row 1/.style={text width=.45\linewidth,text depth=2ex},
row 2/.style={nodes={font=\footnotesize, text width=.45\linewidth,text depth=6cm}}
] 
{
|[fill=Orange!30]| Local Case & |[fill=Green!30]| Global case \\
|[fill=Yellow!30]|
\begin{itemize}
   \item{We have \[\left[\bar \theta\right]=\left[\bar\partial (h^{-1}\partial h)\right]=c_1(\mathcal L)\,
            =\left[K\right]\]}
   \item{Since  $h=\exp(\mathcal K)$ we have:
        \[\theta = \exp(-\mathcal K)\partial (\exp(\mathcal K))\,
            =\tikzmark{Kpot}{$\partial\mathcal K$}\]}            
\end{itemize}
\tikzmark{Kpot2}{\scriptsize So a K\"ahler transf. corresponds to a gauge transformation}
& 
|[fill=Cyan!30]|
\begin{itemize}
    \item{$\mathcal L$ is a flat bundle i.e $h=cst$}
    \item{Since $\theta \sim \partial h$, we can choose a vanishing connection:
        \[
            \theta=\bar \theta=0
        \]}
\end{itemize}\\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\tikz[overlay, remember picture]{%
    \draw[->,red] (Kpot.south) -- (Kpot2.north);
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. you delete `drew` from the code since it cannot be placed there or you just forgot it ?

Comment: @MedVall what draw?  You mean the red arrow?

Comment: Yes  I mean the red arrow

Comment: @MedVall, I am not sure so I need to ask you: do you want the arrow going from that result to the text below?

Comment: I wanted to drow an arrow from the `node` **Kpot** ($\partial\mathcal K$) to the node **Kpot2** (So a K\"ahler transf. corresponds to a gauge transformation )

Comment: @MedVall See edit.

Comment: Thanks again. It does not work in XelaTeX !

Comment: @MedVall What error do you get? Let me try.... Ah, do you get weird symbols instead of math symbols?

Comment: No, it just shifts the arrow

Comment: @MedVall That is odd.

Comment: I do not understand why but I just added `\newcount\pdftexversion \pdftexversion140 \def\pgfsysdriver{pgfsys-dvipdfm.def}` before `\usepackage{tikz}` and it works fine. I found this from [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/229500/tikzmark-and-xelatex) .  this is weird since you did not use the `tikzlibrary` `tikzmark` !!.

Comment: In fact, the trick in the above comment does not always work

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `TiKZ-matrix` you prefer to use `tcolorboxes`. Text is easily compound inside a `tcolorbox` than inside a `node`. With a `tcbraster` your boxes can be distributed like a matrix. And, of course, `tikzmark` is compatible with them.

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{tcbitemize}[raster columns=2, 
    raster column skip=0pt, 
    raster row skip=0pt,
    raster equal height=rows,
    arc=0mm,
    boxrule=0pt,
    coltitle=black,
    ]
\tcbitem[colbacktitle=Orange!30, colback=Yellow!20, adjusted title= Local Case]
\begin{itemize}
   \item We have \[\left[\bar \theta\right]=\left[\bar\partial (h^{-1}\partial h)\right]=c_1(\mathcal L)\,
            =\left[K\right]\] 
   \item Since  $h=\exp(\mathcal K)$ we have:
        \[\theta = \exp(-\mathcal K)\partial (\exp(\mathcal K))\,
            =\partial\mathcal K\tikzmark{Kpot}\]            
\end{itemize}
\tikzmark{Kpot2}So a Kähler transf. corresponds to a gauge transformation.
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\draw[red, shorten >=1mm, shorten <=1mm, ->] ([yshift=1mm]pic cs:Kpot) -- ++(0:3mm) |- ([shift={(-3mm,5mm)}]pic cs:Kpot2)|-([shift={(0mm,1mm)}]pic cs:Kpot2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\tcbitem[colbacktitle=Green!30, colback=Cyan!30, adjusted title=Global Case]
\begin{itemize}
    \item $\mathcal L$ is a flat bundle i.e $h=cst$
    \item Since $\theta \sim \partial h$, we can choose a vanishing connection:
        \[
            \theta=\bar \theta=0
        \]
\end{itemize}
\tcbitem[colbacktitle=Red!30, colback=Orange!40, adjusted title= Local Case]
\begin{itemize}
   \item We have \[\left[\bar \theta\right]=\left[\bar\partial (h^{-1}\partial h)\right]=c_1(\mathcal L)\,
            =\left[K\right]\] 
   \item Since  $h=\exp(\mathcal K)$ we have:
        \[\theta = \exp(-\mathcal K)\partial (\exp(\mathcal K))\,
            =\partial\mathcal K\]            
\end{itemize}
So a Kähler transf. corresponds to a gauge transformation.
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\draw[red, shorten >=1mm, shorten <=1mm, ->] ([yshift=1mm]pic cs:Kpot) -- ++(0:3mm) |- ([shift={(-3mm,5mm)}]pic cs:Kpot2)|-([shift={(0mm,1mm)}]pic cs:Kpot2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\tcbitem[colbacktitle=Purple!30, colback=Blue!30, adjusted title=Global Case]
\begin{itemize}
    \item $\mathcal L$ is a flat bundle i.e $h=cst$
    \item Since $\theta \sim \partial h$, we can choose a vanishing connection:
        \[
            \theta=\bar \theta=0
        \]
\end{itemize}
\end{tcbitemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Update:

Consider this like a long comment instead of an answer. OP comments about using a `matrix` for multiline colored tables like [this one](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B56H9GzWKsB6VU1LRW8wY1hoelE/view). I think this is just a colorful tabular and package `colortbl` can be used for this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[table,svgnames]{xcolor}
%\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\begin{document}

\def\arraystretch{2}
\setlength\arrayrulewidth{0.6pt} % see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/53935/1952
\begin{tabular}{l|l}
\rowcolor{Orange!30}Local Case & Global Case \\ \hline
\rowcolor{Red!30}\ \textbullet\ \# $\text{vector multiplets}\equiv n = \dim \mathcal{M}$ 
&
\ \textbullet\ \# $\text{vector multiplets}\equiv n = \dim \mathcal{M}$ 
\\\hline
\rowcolor{Cyan!30}\ \textbullet\ \# $\text{vector fields}\equiv \overline{n} = n$ 
&
\ \textbullet\ \# $\text{vector fields}\equiv \overline{n} = n + \textcolor{red}{1}\tikzmark{a}$\tikz[remember picture, overlay]\draw[red] ([yshift=0.75ex]pic cs:a)--++(0.25,.25) node[right]{graviphoton}; 
\\\hline
\rowcolor{Blue!30}\ \textbullet\ \# $\text{Rank of SV} \equiv 2\overline{n} = 2n$ 
&
\ \textbullet\ \# $\text{Rank of SV} \equiv 2\overline{n} = 2n+2$ 
\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. But, I used `matrix` since I have multi-lines in another case 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B56H9GzWKsB6VU1LRW8wY1hoelE

Comment: @MedVall. I think you forgot to make public your link. At least I could not read it.

Comment: Sorry, I  now made it public.(I still have a problem about how to draw an arrow from "1" to "graviphoton" (with XeLaTeX))

Comment: @MedVall Did you consider to use a simple colored tabular (with `colortbl` package) for [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B56H9GzWKsB6VU1LRW8wY1hoelE/view) example?

Comment: No, I used only the matrix , I fixed the position, [this](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B56H9GzWKsB6aGY5bkk3N3Bvcjg) is the code that I wrote.

Comment: @MedVall I think that you want colorful tabulars then, why do you use `matrix`? Please, take a look at my updated answer.

Comment: Great !, your method is perfect :) . Thanks a lot